# Performing 'UNION' on the queries with 'ORDER BY'

Tags: sql-server

I am getting a syntax error at the `Union all`. I know I can't do this. But Can somebody help me out.

```
SELECT
ID, 
date1, 
date2 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 DESC )  as RN1, 
1 as Range
FROM 
(
SELECT ID,date1,
rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 )
FROM listing_History   (nolock)
WHERE [date1] <=   CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()))  AND 
ID in (SELECT txt FROM [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@listStr, ',')) 
)  AS A ORDER BY date1 DESC, date2 DESC

UNION ALL 

SELECT
ID, 
Date1, 
date2 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 DESC )  as RN1, 
1 as Range
FROM 
(
SELECT 
ID,
date1,
rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 )
FROM listing_History   (nolock)
WHERE [status_date] <=   CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) -1)
AND 
ID in (SELECT txt FROM [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@listStr, ',')) 
) AS A ORDER BY date1 DESC,date2 desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `ORDER BY`s from every `UNION` except the last one and make sure the column names you reference in the `ORDER BY` correspond to the first `SELECT`.

Comment: but I need to do the order By for each query before performing the union

Comment: You have the order by in your ranking function for each `SELECT` so it is fine.  If you want to rank everything all together, after the `UNION`ing, say so and I'll have a new answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

There should always one `Order by` on the very **last** select of `UNION` and `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT  
ID,
date1,
date2 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 DESC )  as RN1,
1 as Range
FROM 
(
SELECT ID,date1,
rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 )
FROM listing_History (nolock)
WHERE [date1] <= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())) 
AND 
ID in (SELECT txt FROM [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@listStr, ',')) 
) AS A --ORDER BY date1 DESC, date2 DESC Remove order by from here

UNION ALL 

SELECT
ID, 
Date1, 
date2 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 DESC )  as RN1, 
1 as Range
FROM 
(
SELECT ID,date1,
rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1 )
FROM listing_History with(nolock)
WHERE [status_date] <=   CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()))
AND 
ID in (SELECT txt FROM [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@listStr, ',')) 
)AS A
ORDER BY date1 DESC, date2 DESC
```

Comment: but I need to do the order By for each query before perfoming the union

Comment: @BumbleBee. It will give the result in `ORDER` even if you do order by once.

Comment: In the later part of the query I am selecting the rows whose RN1 = 1. so i was assuming that the order by at the end would not give the right RN1.

Comment: You cannot put `ORDER BY` inside a subquery either.  Regardless of the order the result of this query are, you will always have at least 2 rows `WHERE RN = 1`.